# PDDocument.load(url) isn't a method

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I'm currently working with PDFBox version 3.0.1 and I'm facing a challenge when trying to load a PDF from a URL. It appears that there isn't a specific method provided for this purpose.

Below is the code snippet I've attempted, but it's not functioning as expected:

```java
public void loadPDF(String url, String name) throws IOException {
    PDDocument document = null;
    URL pdfUrl = new URL(url);
    URLConnection urlConnection = pdfUrl.openConnection();
    InputStream ip = urlConnection.getInputStream();
    BufferedInputStream bf = new BufferedInputStream(ip);
    try {
        document = Loader.loadPDF((RandomAccessRead) ip);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Assert.fail("Could not load PDF. Please check the URL again");
    }
}
```

Could someone please provide guidance or an alternative approach for loading a PDF from a URL in PDFBox 3.0.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `InputStream` obtained from an `URLConnection` does not implement `org.apache.pdfbox.io.RandomAccessRead`, so that cast will fail.

You'll need to use `Loader.loadPDF(RandomAccessReadBuffer.createBufferFromStream(is))` (and get rid of the construction of that `BufferedInputStream` as you shouldn't need that). That will call [`Loader.loadPDF(RandomAccessRead)`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox/3.0.1/org/apache/pdfbox/Loader.html#loadPDF-org.apache.pdfbox.io.RandomAccessRead-) with an instance of [`RandomAccessReadBuffer`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox-io/3.0.1/org/apache/pdfbox/io/RandomAccessReadBuffer.html) (which does implement `RandomAccessRead`).